# Как подождать полной загрузки скрипта гугл аналитики?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, yandex-metrika-api

На страницу с помощью js скрипта ставится 2 счетчика:
яндекс метрика
гугл аналитика.

В дальнейшем производятся манипуляции с их куками и данымми.

Возникают ситуации когда счетчики (скрипты подгружаемые от яндекса и гугла) не успевают поставиться на страницу, а манипуляции в скрипте уже происходят, которые становятся из-за этого некорректыными.

У яндекса в АПИ есть возможность отследить завершение установки счетчика асинхронно и затем уже манипулировать им :

```html
document.addEventListener('yacounter123456789inited', function() {
// выполнить этот код если счетчик загружен
}
```

разработка на дев сервере ведется,
    вот пример

```html
addMetric ('GA', 'UA-102241230-1');
showCookie('_ga');
function addMetric(type, counterID){
        switch (type) {
            case 'GA':
                if (counterID !== null) {
                    var scriptGA = '(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,\'script\',\'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js\',\'ga\');ga(\'create\', \'' + counterID + '\', \'auto\');ga(\'send\', \'pageview\');';
                    var createGA = document.createElement('script');
                    createGA.innerHTML = scriptGA;
                    document.body.appendChild(createGA);
                }break;
        }
    }
```

Если analytics.js не успеет загрузиться, то showCookie('_ga') покажет - undefined

Есть такой же функционал у гугл? как правильно его использовать?

Comment: `The tracking code is designed to read data from your page after the content for the page has finished loading. For this reason, the snippet should be located just before the closing </body> tag for your web page.` 
А чем вам не подходит ответ от самого гугла?
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview#trackingCodePlacement

Comment: с ответом гугла полностью согласен, скрипт там и создается, но он тянет за собой analytics.js, который может грузиться дольше чем скрипт исполняемый на основной странице использующий параметры из analytics.js. Из-за этого тянуться ошибки.
В апи яндекса можно подождать полной загрузки их скрипта и счетчика, а в гугл как отловить событие полной загрузки?

Comment: а вы можете дать ссылку на саму страницу, где у вас это происходит. Просто так проще дать рекомендацию.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.
В Google Analytics для выполнения функций после полной загрузки счетчика необходимо воспользоваться встроенной функцией ga(callback).
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference?hl=ru

т.е. 
функция

```html
ga(function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

будет выполнена только после полной загрузки счетчика гугл